# Reading an API output

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to calculate the cost of 1 bitcoin in ZAR. 
Here is the code currently:

```
# access order book, display what 1 BTC will cost

#create order book variable
import requests
ob=requests.get('https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/orderbook?pair=XBTZAR').json()

btc=0.0
rand=0



while btc<1.0:
    for item in ob['asks']:
        print([item['price'], item['volume']]) 
        btc=btc + float(item['volume'])
print(btc)
```

The output from the API will look as follows: https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/orderbook?pair=XBTZAR

The program is supposed to add the next "volume" value to btc and its corresponding price to rand until btc>1. Then it must just print btc (because it should be just more than one usually) and the average of the prices it had to add to rand.

The specific part I am struggling with is to get the program to choose only 1 set of "price" and volume" and then add those to btc and rand before it reiterates the while loop. It must add one price to rand and one volume to btc at a time, and exit the while loop when btc is greater than one.

Thank you in advance
Marius

Comment: Please include a sample of your data and the expected output

Comment: The API link is included above, it gives the data as follow: {"timestamp":1506400154334,"asks":[{"price":"54601.00","volume":"0.756687"},{"price":"54601.00","volume":"0.072439"},{"price":"54601.00","volume":"0.30"},...

Comment: Expected output is something like:

Comment: btc=1.007, rand=54 000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you check if this works?

```
for item in ob['asks']:
    print([item['price'], item['volume']]) 
    if btc < 1:
       btc=btc + float(item['volume'])
       rand = rand + float(item['price'])
       print(btc)
```

Comment: It is an improvement. However, it prints all the values for "price" and "volume". It must only print the "price" values for which the accumulative btc<1

Comment: Move the print(btc) line within the if block then. Edited the answer too.

Comment: Ok I get what you did there. If the print function is passed, though, the program already prints the entire list in the dict "asks", which includes all of the prices and volumes. How can I get it to target only one set of "price" and "volume" at a time? So: while btc<1, add one more set of "price" and "volume" to rand and btc, respectively. Sorry for making this so long.

Comment: There you go. If you want to print volume and price only as long as btc < 1, then move the first print statement inside the if block.

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated